# How to pass a value from loop of JSP page to another JSP page?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have recently started working with JSP and I am trying to pass *rollno* value from one page to another. However, it is always passing the last row *rollno*.

Below is my first JSP page from where I'm taking values and also feepay page where I retrieve those values. I have tried appending *rollno* to URL but that didn't work either.

Please help me with this.

```
<%
  String id=session.getAttribute("rollno").toString();
  int  idd=Integer.parseInt(id);
%>
```

---

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>ROLL NO</th>
      <th>FEE</th>
      <th>FEE PAID</th>
      <th>FEE PENDING</th>
      <th>PAY FEE</th>
    </tr>           
    <% while(resultset.next()){ %>
    <TR>
      <TD> <%= resultset.getString(1) %></td>
      <TD> <%= resultset.getString(2) %></TD><% String rollno=resultset.getString(2).toString(); %>
      <TD><%= resultset.getString(3) %></TD>
      <td><%= resultset.getString(4) %></td>
      <td><%= resultset.getString(5) %></td>
      <TD><a href="feepaypage.jsp" onclick="<%= session.setAttribute("rollno",resultset.getString(2)) %>">Pay Fee</a></TD>                                   
    </TR>
    <% } %>                
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** your `overwriting` the `session` in  while loop so only you always getting `last row` value .

**2nd :** Just pass it like `query string` `get parameter` like below

```
 <TD><a href="feepaypage.jsp?rollno=<%=resultset.getString(2) %>" >Pay Fee</a></TD>
```

**3rd :** Access the `get parameter` like below

```
<%
String id=request.getParameter("rollno").toString();
int  idd=Integer.parseInt(id);
%>
```